# Prove following statement about Kruskal Algorithm

Tags: graphs, greedy-algorithms, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-trees

Let G be undirected graph, G=(V,E), and all edge weights are distinct. Consider an edge e=(u,v)∈E that wasn't included in the solution obtained from applying Kruskal Algorithm to G. Prove that this edge isn't in any Minimimum Spanning Tree of G.

Comment: Do you perhaps also have that all edge weights are distinct?

Comment: Yes, all edge weights are distinct.

Comment: You should probably include that In  your first sentence in your question statement

Comment: If this is quoted content, please attribute it properly - hyperlink welcome. Consider using a *block quote* (see, e.g, post editor tool bar "quotation mark button (`"`)).

Answer (score 0):

Without additional assumptions about the edge weights that's false. A simple counterexample is a triangle graph where all edge weights are equal.